# Why does a Websocket client need to send close frame to server rather than just reconnect?

Tags: websocket, tcp, tcpclient

Imagine a websocket client detects something is wrong and wishes to restart the websocket connection (via creating a new connection).

Why does the client need to send a close frame, as opposed to just closing the socket/file descriptor and re-connecting?

Does the lack of sending a close frame affect the Client's ability to reconnect via a new connection? I assumed not because that connection's state has been deleted.

Comment: Design Philosophy chapter of RFC-6455 says only:
"includes an additional closing handshake in-band that is designed to work in the presence of proxies and other intermediaries".

Comment: @SKi so not important unless you're writing a websocket library?

Comment: I only find that explanation for the existence of close-frame.  I don't know could it cause some harm with proxies, if the TCP connection is closed without close-frame.